# Eigenspace and linear combination of eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a vector $\boldsymbol{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ that is an eigenvector of some matrix $\boldsymbol{A}$ with eigenvalue 1. So $\boldsymbol{v} \in E_1^A$ i.e. eigenspace of A with eigenvalue 1.

Suppose $\boldsymbol{v}$ is a linear combination of $p$ vectors:

$$\boldsymbol{v} = \beta_1 \boldsymbol{v}_1 + \beta_2 \boldsymbol{v}_2 + \cdot\cdot\cdot + \beta_p \boldsymbol{v}_p$$

Are the $\boldsymbol{v}_i \in E_1^A$ as well?

Comment: Are the $p$ vectors themselves eigenvectors?

Comment: In the case of the question I'm trying to solve they are, but I have to prove that. I have a big matrix $\boldsymbol{v}$ that is an eigenvector. i'm trying to show that the $\boldsymbol{v}_i$s are also eigenvectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily, consider the matrix
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}1& 0\\0 & 2\end{bmatrix}$$
which has the eigenvector $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix} \in E^A_1$, but 
$$\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0.5\\0.5\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}0.5\\-0.5\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: You are right, thank you!